# diagonal difference OutOfRange Exception C#

Tags: c#, difference, diagonal

I have to write a program that finds the difference between the sums of square matrix diagonals for homework, but my code throws IndexOutOFRange exception and I have no idea how to fix it.

Source code below:
//input  3  11 2 4  4 5 6  10 8 -12  //desired output: 15

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


    class diagonalDifference
    {
        static void Main()
        {

    int N = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    int[,] arr = new int[N, N];
    string str = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        string[] strArr = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        for (int j = 0; j < strArr.Length; ++j)
        {
            arr[i, j] = Convert.ToInt16(strArr[j]);
        }
    }

    int left = 0, right = N - 1, ldTotal = 0, rdTotal = 0;
    while (left <= right)
    {


    ldTotal += arr[left, left];


    rdTotal += arr[left++, right];
    }    

    Console.WriteLine(Math.Abs(ldTotal - rdTotal));



     }
        }
```

Comment: On what line of code do you get the exception? You can check it in StackTrace property of the exception while running a debugger.

Comment: i get it on: 
 ldTotal += arr[left, left];

Comment: Presented code should get stuck on `while (N > 0)    ldTotal += arr[left, left];` since it's infinite loop. Are there any curly brackets? Also `left` variable is never changed. Please clarify the code.

Comment: Yes, there are curly brackets. This is my first post to Stackoverflow so I had some difficulties. The while loop should be like this:
while (N > 0)
{
IdTotal += arr[left, left];
rdTotal += arr[left++; right];
}

Comment: @Peter.Petrov if n>0 the loop will be infinite..where is the condition to fail?

Comment: The IndexOutOfRange exception states: index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: @Peter.Petrov if the while loop condition didn't fail the loop will be infinite and out of the index will cause for sure

Comment: What you want to do in the loop exactly?

Comment: Always validate user input.  You require `strArr.Length == N` to make your program work.  So test for that and complain when it isn't the case.

Comment: I want the loop to find the difference between the sum of the two diagonals.

Comment: You can't make an square matrix with ten inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 class diagonalDifference
    {
        static void Main()
        {

    int N = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    int[,] arr = new int[N, N];
    string str = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        string[] strArr = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        for (int j = 0; j < strArr.Length; ++j)
        {
            arr[i, j] = Convert.ToInt16(strArr[j]);
        }
    }

    int left = 0, right = N - 1, ldTotal = 0, rdTotal = 0;
    while (left <= (N-1))
    {


    ldTotal += arr[left, left];


    rdTotal += arr[left, right];
Left++;
Right--;
    }    

    Console.WriteLine(Math.Abs(ldTotal - rdTotal));



     }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Will do! Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

class Result
{

```
/*
 * Complete the 'diagonalDifference' function below.
 *
 * The function is expected to return an INTEGER.
 * The function accepts 2D_INTEGER_ARRAY arr as parameter.
 */

public static int diagonalDifference(List<List<int>> arr)
{
    int l=arr.Count;
    int d1=0;
    int d2=0;
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
    d1=d1+arr[i][i];
    d2=d2+arr[i][l-1-i];
    }
    return (Math.Abs(d1-d2));
}
```

}